# Why are min and max temperatures (TN TX) not published in TAFs in the United States?

Tags: weather, usa, temperature, taf

I know that other countries like Brazil, Argentina, etc. do publish minimum and maximum temperatures in their Terminal Aerodrome Forecasts, abbreviated TN and TX. But why are they not shown in TAFs in the United States? (I guess other countries in Europe also have the temperatures).

BTW, where are the expected min and max temperatures in the US published in an official report? NOAA/NWS? WX-BRIEF?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't much of an explanation, but [the National Weather Service says](https://www.aviationweather.gov/static/help/taf-decode.php):

> The international TAF also contains forecast temperature, icing, and
>   turbulence. These three elements are not included in National Weather
>   Service (NWS) prepared TAFs. The U.S. has no requirement to forecast
>   temperatures in an aerodrome forecast

That sounds to me like "we don't think it's worth it". There are various temperature forecasts on the NWS aviation site ([icing level](https://www.aviationweather.gov/icing/frzlvl), [surface temperatures](https://www.aviationweather.gov/windtemp/plot), [graphical area forecast](http://new.aviationweather.gov/areafcst)) but personally speaking, I get low/high temperature information from regular, non-aviation forecasts. You can get those forecasts from [the NWS site](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.22221656694211&lon=-85.68080179316746#.VzTN7YQwgdU) too, if that's what you mean by "official".